# Parse the Some User Define boolean Expression String in java

Tags: java, string, parsing

> like 1.  true AND true
>
> like 2.  true AND true OR (true AND false)
>
> like 3.  NOT true

so ,how we can parse above like example expression easier , or any java api for string parser

Comment: only need to parse the ,

    like 1. true AND true

    like 2. true AND true OR (true AND false)

    like 3. NOT true

Comment: So. You want to replace 1 and 2 with `true` , `false` etc. Can you show us exact input and expected output?

Comment: Hello @Jens and all members why this topic consider as a off-topic
and i already got the answer and , find from spring expression, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MVEL API. MVEL is a hybrid dynamic/statically typed, embeddable Expression Language and runtime for the Java Platform. It is an open source.

Answer (score 0):

If we are using Spring then use folloing SpelExpressionParser parse it , dynamic and also allow the && and AND operation also

```
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
boolean falseValue = parser.parseExpression("true && ( false || ( false && true ) )").getValue(Boolean.class);
System.out.println(falseValue);
falseValue = parser.parseExpression("true AND ( false OR ( false AND true ) )").getValue(Boolean.class);
System.out.println(falseValue);
```